# How to check if mat[j][i]>mat[j+1][i] with rows of different length?

Tags: java

hello i have to do the following exercise:
Write an iterative e1 method with the following characteristics:

- e1 has as its only parameter m a two-dimensional array (matrix) of integers;
- e1 returns true if, for each row, except the last one, there is at least one element that is strictly less than that which occupies the same position, but on the next row. In any other case, e1 returns false.

my solution :

```java
public static boolean e1(int m[][]){
    boolean conferma=false;
    boolean exit=false;
    if(m==null || m.length==0){
        return false;
    }
    if(!conferma){
        for (int i = 0 ;!exit && i<m.length-1;i++){
            if(m[i]!=null){
                for (int j = 0 ;!conferma && j<m[i].length-1;j++){
                    if(m[j+1]!=null){
                        if(m[j+1][i]!=null){
                            if(m[j][i]>m[j+1][i]){
                                conferma=true;
                            }
                        }

                    }

                }
            }
            if (conferma){
                exit=true;
            }

        }
    }
    return conferma;
}
```

input of this exercise :

```java
import java.util.Arrays;
public class EsameD1819TestE1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[][] m0 = null;
        System.out.println("Caso  1:"+(EsameD1819.e1(m0)==false));

        int[][] m1 = {};
        System.out.println("Caso  2:"+(EsameD1819.e1(m1)==false));

        int[][] m2 = {{1}};
        System.out.println("Caso  3:"+(EsameD1819.e1(m2)==false));

        int[][] m3 = {{1}
                     ,{2}};
        System.out.println("Caso  4:"+(EsameD1819.e1(m3)==true));

        int[][] m4 = {{1}
                     ,{1,2}};
        System.out.println("Caso  5:"+(EsameD1819.e1(m4)==false));

        int[][] m5 = {{0,1}
                     ,{0,2,3}
                     ,{1,2}};
        System.out.println("Caso  6:"+(EsameD1819.e1(m5)==true));

        int[][] m6 = {{0,1}
                     ,{0,2,3}
                     ,null};
        System.out.println("Caso  7:"+(EsameD1819.e1(m6)==false));

        int[][] m7 = {{0,1}
                     ,null
                     ,{0,2,3}};
        System.out.println("Caso  8:"+(EsameD1819.e1(m7)==false));

        int[][] m8 = {{0,1}
                     ,{0,2,3}
                     ,{0,4}
                     ,{0,5,3}};
        System.out.println("Caso  9:"+(EsameD1819.e1(m8)==true));

        int[][] m9 = {null
                     ,null
                     ,null};
        System.out.println("Caso 10:"+(EsameD1819.e1(m9)==false));
    }
}
```

my output:

```
Caso  1:true
Caso  2:true
Caso  3:true
Caso  4:false
Caso  5:true
Caso  6:false
Caso  7:true
Caso  8:true
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 2 out of bounds for length 2
        at EsameD1819.e1(EsameD1819.java:41)
        at EsameD1819TestE1.main(EsameD1819TestE1.java:41)
```

expected output:

```
Caso  1:true
Caso  2:true
Caso  3:true
Caso  4:true
Caso  5:true
Caso  6:true
Caso  7:true
Caso  8:true
Caso  9:true
```

Comment: There are several locations in the code that you may benefit from using a break statement https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_break.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can understand the 7th test assumption is wrong since:

```
m6[0][1] < m6[1][1] = true; // 1 < 2

int[][] m6 = { { 0, 1 }, { 0, 2, 3 }, null };
System.out.println("Caso  7:" + (e1(m6) == false));
```

.. so this should be

```
System.out.println("Caso  7:" + (e1(m6) == true));
```

shouldn't it?

```
private static boolean e1(int m[][]) {
    if (m == null)
        return false;
    for (int i = 0, n=1; n < m.length; ++i, ++n) {
        if (m[i] != null && m[n] != null) {
            for (int j = 0; j < m[i].length && j < m[n].length; ++j) {
                if (m[i][j] < m[n][j])
                    return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer , that works fine and give me new way to think for  problems like this... and for  the 7th test assumption i was thinking the same

Answer (score -1):

You are mixing up rows and column indexes. `i` must be the row index and `j` the column index.

```
if (m[i + 1] != null) {
    if (m[i][j] > m[i + 1][j]) {
        conferma = true;
     }
}
```

Comment: hello, i is the row index and j in column index ... check code

Comment: @Singh `m.length` gives the number of rows and not columns

Comment: ignoring the fact that rows and colunms can both be the first or second array: in the 9th line you posted, you check m[i] `m[i]!=null` i indexing by the external loop. in line 11, you check m[j] `m[j+1]!=null`. If you have an array that is wider than it is tall, you will atempt to look at an array that does not exist.

Comment: @deef0000dragon1   i think doing j<m[i].length-1 ... in this way m[j+1]!=null is ok and u dont check m[m[i].length]

Answer (score -2):

Your issue has nothing do to with differents lengths per se, but with SHORTER following lines. There are two possible solutions for the problem:

1. Use a try-catch construct to catch the IndexOutOfBoundsException and return false.
2. Check for the array length **before** attempting to access an index by comparing `m.length` to j and `m[j].length` to i.

While the first option is definitely easier to write, it is often considered to be bad code style (And harder to read), because you're using Exceptions to control the flow of your code instead of simple if-Statements.

Comment: "Exceptions are for exceptional circumstances."

Comment: *Use a try-catch construct to catch the IndexOutOfBoundsException* - Definitely not a great option

Comment: @deef0000dragon1 Mind to clarify that? Did you mean "Don't recommend exceptions" or "Don't advise against exceptions"?

Comment: @user7 Quote: "While the first option is definitely easier to write, it is often considered to be bad code style [...] because you're using Exceptions to control the flow of your code instead of simple if-Statements"

Comment: @Nightara exceptional: unusual; not typical. If you have a circumstance where you know the typical flow, you should **not** be using exceptions. Exceptions are for making sure if something happens that is not typical, data exists that shouldnt, or doesent exist where it should etc. Only then should you use exceptions to attempt to recover the program.